# stable/queens branch successful install but iptables were "forgotten" after reboot

Tags: openstack

I installed openstack with the devstack repo following these steps [at this link](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/#install-linux) but I switched to the `stable/queens` branch before running the ./stack.sh script.
Just like the question title states, everything seemed fine but I rebooted and the iptables were gone.

**Is there an included script in the repo to get them up again?**

Comment: Why not just start over?

Comment: Well, that's a possibility, but the linux installation takes about 20mins, the repo download takes a couple of mins and the ./stack.sh script takes a full hour. Also, I bet I'm not the only one who will face this problem, additionally, I'm expecting on answers someonce could warn me about what other things can be misconfigured by rebooting. In the mean time, I already did some research so in the case of having to start over I'll save the ip tables to a file and then reload them like so `sudo iptables-restore < file`